# Trouble getting unique column values

Tags: shell, awk, command-line

Trying to get unique column using `awk`  I need column 8 to be unique.  My separator is `|&|`

```
awk -F "|&|" '!($8 in a){a[$1];print}' < file_b.log
```

Sorry file looks like this.

```
a|&|1.....|&|steve
a|&|1.....|&|josh
a|&|1.....|&|steve
a|&|1.....|&|matt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you haven't given sample of Input_file or sample of expected output so couldn't test it. Could you please try following.

```
awk -F'\\|&\\|' '!a[$8]++' Input_file
```